# Struts 2 Action Thread Safety When Accessing Static Methods

Tags: java, struts2, thread-safety, static-methods

I know that Struts 2 Actions are thread safe. But what happens if those Action classes contains method calls to utility static methods? Will thread safety be compromised?

Take a utility method that will parse an uploaded excel file etc. If the method is to be declared static should it be synchronized?

**Update:**

I'm just reading the file, and the file is submitted to the action so in itself it should be thread safe... But Since the parsing is done in a utility method I'm having doubts whether synchronization is necessary or not. But apparently if you are accessing only method scope variables it should be thread safe. But does parameters like File fall under that category?

Comment: file you mean which is being submitted to the action? if that is the case it will for each request and will not be shared.

Comment: Show some code, otherwise we're just guessing. A parameter *is* a method-scope variable by definition. You may want to brush up on some Java basics before proceeding too much further.

Comment: Primitive parameters, yes. Reference mutable objects not so much.. Brushed up enough for yeh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding thread safety will not be compromised until unless you are playing around with share data between threads.you must take care of atomicity, visibility, etc.

IF there are any method level variables are replicated in each thread execution stack and only race conditions can arises if there is any shared data and for such we need to take care of.

Though The stack is local to the current thread, but there can be references to shared objects on that stack.

Comment: Action classes are thread local. But any static method is visible to the entire JVM right? So how can it be thread safe without synchronization? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Thihara:what i am saying issue will only arise when u will try to do some operation on shared data, local variable will not be subjected to this problem

Comment: If your static method is accessing your excel file, then it must be synchronized. You must ensure that resources are not accessed concurrently. This also applies to non-atomic objects in the session.
If you only have read access to the resources, then this is usually not a problem (except iterators).